# Отсортировать массив учитывая "_" (underscore)

Tags: php, массивы

Предположим есть массив:
`$array = ['David', 'Anna', '_Spider', 'Spider_Man', 'Max'];`
Мне нужно отсортировать его по алфавиту.
Есть в php такая функция как sort, и она меня в принципе удовлетворяет, но если не один её минус - она не учитывает `_`. Может ли кто-то сделать массив, по такому примеру:
`_Spider, Spider_Man, Anna, David, Max` (расположения слов с `_` мне не важно, главное чтобы они были первыми, либо последними).

Comment: функции `sort` и `rsort` так и сортируют: слова с `_` либо в конце, либо в начале соответственно. Что не так? И тот пример, который вы привели - там вообще непонятно, какая сортировка имеется в виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно строки, которые содержат символ `_` поместить либо в начало отсортированного массива, либо в конец, строки не содержащие символа `_` отсортировать по алфавиту.

Тогда для решения нужна более *хитрая* функция [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a_has_underscore = strpos($a, '_') !== false; // строка $a содержит символ `_`
    $b_has_underscore = strpos($b, '_') !== false; // строка $b содержит символ `_`
    if ($a_has_underscore && !$b_has_underscore) {
        // если строка $a содержит символ `_`, а строка $b нет, возвращаем -1
        // это говорит о том, что строка $a меньше строки $b
        return -1; 
    }
    if (!$a_has_underscore && $b_has_underscore) {
        // если строка $a не содержит символ `_`, а строка $b содержит, возвращаем 1
        // это говорит о том, что строка $a больше строки $b
        return 1;
    }
    // если обе строки содержат символ `_` или обе не содержат, то сравниваем их
    // функция strcasecmp() вернет отрицательное число, если $a меньше $b,
    // положительное число, если $a больше $b и 0, если равны
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
});
```

Этот пример поставит строки с символом `_` в начало массива.

```
Array
(
    [0] => _Spider
    [1] => Spider_Man
    [2] => Anna
    [3] => David
    [4] => Max
)
```

Если нужно поставить строки с символом `_` в конец, то в примере нужно поменять местами `-1` и `1`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь